# Trying to do a stored function to return the annual salary of an employee but i expected it to work but it didn't work

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

3. Create a stored function ANNUAL_COMP to return the annual salary of an employee when passed their salary and commission percentage.
   NOTE: Annual Salary = salary * (1 + commission_pct).
   •   The function should address NULL values therefore use the NVL( ) function.
   •   Use the stored function in a SELECT statement against the EMPLOYEES table.

I tried this but didn't work

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    ANNUAL_COMP (v_sal IN employees.salary%TYPE, v_comm IN employees.comission_pct%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN (NVL(v_sal,0) * (NVL(1 + v_comm);
END ANNUAL_COMP;
/
```

```sql
SELECT employee_id, last_name, ANNUAL_COMP(salary,commission_pct)
FROM employees;
```

it says Error(8,42): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     . ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec as between || multiset member submultiset

Answer (score 0):

`RETURN` clause has errors, as the 2nd `NVL` lacks in the 2nd argument.

```
RETURN NVL(v_sal,0) * NVL(1 + v_comm, 0);
```

Also, column name (in declaration) should have two `M` (`coMMission_pct`).

Finally, I don't have your table, but - what value does the `commission_pct` contain? If that's really *percentage*, I guess you should actually divide it by 100 (that's what I did in my code):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION annual_comp (
  2     v_sal   IN employees.salary%TYPE,
  3     v_comm  IN employees.commission_pct%TYPE)
  4     RETURN NUMBER
  5  IS
  6  BEGIN
  7     RETURN NVL (v_sal, 0) * NVL (v_comm/100, 0);
  8  END annual_comp;
  9  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT employee_id, last_name, annual_comp (salary, commission_pct) result FROM employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME      RESULT
----------- ---------- ----------
       7499 ALLEN            4800
       7521 WARD             6250
       7654 MARTIN          17500
       7698 BLAKE               0
       7844 TURNER              0
       7900 JAMES               0

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```